# NoSuchMethodError: model.AddEvents.getStartDate()Ljava/lang/String;

Tags: java, jsp, javabeans, nosuchmethoderror

I don't know what's happening here. I used Date data type to save my data in my database and it's keep giving this error-Error Accessing Database:javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: model.AddEvents.getStartDate()Ljava/lang/String;.I'm so sure that my servlet part has the error. I think the problem is in the usage of Date type in my servlet and java bean because initially i used string and it worked perfectly.Pls help guys :)

```
   package model;

import java.util.Date;
public class AddEvents{
 private String title;
 private String eventDesc;
 private String StartTime;
 private String  EndTime;
 private double Budget;
 private java.util.Date StartDate;
 private java.util.Date EndDate;

 public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
public String getEventDesc() {
    return eventDesc;
}
public void setEventDesc(String eventDesc) {
    this.eventDesc = eventDesc;
}

public String getStartTime() {
    return StartTime;
}
public void setStartTime(String startTime) {
    StartTime = startTime;
}
public String getEndTime() {
    return EndTime;
}
public void setEndTime(String endTime){
    EndTime=endTime;
}

public double getBudget() {
    return Budget;
}
public void setBudget(double budget) {
    Budget = budget;
}
public java.util.Date getStartDate() {
    return StartDate;
}
public void setStartDate(java.util.Date startDate) {
    StartDate = startDate;
}
public java.util.Date getEndDate() {
    return EndDate;
}
public void setEndDate(java.util.Date endDate) {
    EndDate = endDate;
}

}


AddEventsServlet:
package servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.ListIterator;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import database.DBAO;
import database.Delete;
import model.AddEvents;


/**
 * Servlet implementation class AddEventsServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/AddEventsServlet")
public class AddEventsServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public AddEventsServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //doGet(request, response);


        AddEvents myEvent = new AddEvents();
        //create an object based on the Java class customers


        //Assignment of data
        myEvent.setTitle(request.getParameter("Title"));
        myEvent.setEventDesc(request.getParameter("EventDesc"));
        myEvent.setStartTime(request.getParameter("StartTime"));
        myEvent.setEndTime(request.getParameter("EndTime"));
        myEvent.setBudget(Double.valueOf(request.getParameter("Budget")));
        myEvent.setStartDate(java.sql.Date.valueOf(request.getParameter("StartDate")));
        myEvent.setEndDate(java.sql.Date.valueOf(request.getParameter("EndDate")));

        String title = request.getParameter("Title");
        String eventDesc= request.getParameter("EventDesc");
        String StartTime=request.getParameter("StartTime");
        String EndTime =request.getParameter("EndTime");
        double Budget=Double.valueOf(request.getParameter("Budget") );
        //double Budget=request.getParameter("Budget");
        Date StartDate=java.sql.Date.valueOf(request.getParameter("StartDate"));
        Date EndDate=java.sql.Date.valueOf(request.getParameter("EndDate"));



        System.out.println(myEvent.getTitle());
        System.out.println(myEvent.getEventDesc());
        System.out.println(myEvent.getStartTime());
        System.out.println(myEvent.getEndTime());
        System.out.println(myEvent.getBudget());
        //System.out.println(myEvent.getStartDate());
        //System.out.println(myEvent.getEndDate());
        java.util.Date date = myEvent.getStartDate();
          SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
          System.out.println(sdf.format(date));

          java.util.Date date1 = myEvent.getEndDate();
          SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
          System.out.println(sdf1.format(date1));

        request.setAttribute("Title",title);
        request.setAttribute("Details",eventDesc);
        request.setAttribute("Start Time",StartTime);
        request.setAttribute("End Time",EndTime);
        request.setAttribute("Budget",Budget);
        request.setAttribute("Start Date",StartDate);
        request.setAttribute("End Date",EndDate);

        try
        {
            DBAO myDatabase = new DBAO();
            ArrayList <AddEvents> myEventList = myDatabase.getAddEvents(); //not needed
            //AddEvents myEventDetails =myDatabase.isEvent(myEvent,title, eventDesc, StartTime, EndTime, Budget); //not needed

            HttpSession myRequest = request.getSession(true); //not needed
            request.setAttribute("EventList",myEventList); //not needed
            System.out.println(myEventList.size()); //not needed

            // you comment out the method that insert data to database
            myDatabase.AddEvents(myEvent,title,eventDesc,StartTime,EndTime,Budget,StartDate,EndDate);
            // the dispatcher can go to RetrieveServlet and let it handle the retrieve
            //myDatabase.delete(myEvent,title,eventDesc,StartTime,EndTime,Budget,StartDate,EndDate);
            //name of delete database
            request.getRequestDispatcher("Retrieve.jsp").forward(request, response);

    }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Error Accessing Database:" +ex);
        }

    }

}
```

Retrieve.jsp: Adding this cuz I just realised my console shows error in this jsp page- Retrieve.jsp:java:183 it says

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<%@page import="model.AddEvents,java.util.ArrayList,java.util.ListIterator" %>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>


<script language="javascript">
function deleteRecord(id){
    var f=document.form;
    f.method="AddEvents";
    f.action='delete.jsp?id='+id;
    f.submit();
}
</script>


</head>
<body>
<%!ArrayList<AddEvents> myEventList; //have to declear in a declaration tag for access in the page %>
<% myEventList = (ArrayList<AddEvents>) request.getAttribute("EventList");
if(myEventList.size() == 0)
{
    %>
    <h2>No events</h2>
    <%
}
else
{
    %>

<table>
<%
ListIterator<AddEvents> li = myEventList.listIterator();

while(li.hasNext())
{
    AddEvents myEvent = new AddEvents();
    myEvent= (AddEvents)li.next();
    %>

 <%AddEvents event =(AddEvents)session.getAttribute("Event_Info"); %>
<tr><td>Title:</td><td><%= myEvent.getTitle() %></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>Details:</td><td><%= myEvent.getEventDesc() %></td><td> </td></tr>
<tr><td>StartTime:</td><td><%=myEvent.getStartTime() %></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>EndTime:</td><td><%= myEvent.getEndTime() %></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>Budget:</td><td><%=myEvent.getBudget()%></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>StartDate:</td><td><%=myEvent.getStartDate() %></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>EndDate:</td><td><%=myEvent.getEndDate() %></td>
<tr><td> <a href="delete.jsp"><img border="0" alt="delete" src="deleteIcon.png" width="20" height="20"></a></td>
<td><a href="AddEvent.jsp"><img border="0" alt="update" src="updateIcon.png" width="100" height="100"></a></td>
</tr>

<%}


%>
</table>
<%
}
%>
<input id='eventID' type="hidden" name="hiddEvent" value="">
<a href="AddEvent.jsp">Add Event</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the `AddEvents` class ?

Comment: @Berger My java bean class

Comment: Could you add that class to your question ?

Comment: Add code of `AddEvents` class and also tell me a reason that why are you getting parameter values again from request as you already used them to set events (seems in your code..)

Comment: I just added the class and removedthe Servlet codes cuz I cant post both. It's keeping saying i need to add more info :(

Comment: Usually `NoSuchMethodError` indicates a class loading issue. It can happen if you are compiling your application against one library (jar) version and running it against another. This happens when some of the jars that you use to build your app have different versions deployed in the application server (which is likely in your case). I can't see your servlet code so I can't really say.

Comment: @Lisha ,Never declare any private variable with Capital(Bolck) letter as `StartDate` it should be as `stratDate` since when you create getter/setter method then it generate method like `getStartDate()`, assuming that variable name is starts with small character.

Comment: @Mustafa she added a servlet code before, but removed it and added model class. However if you want to look at previous post, click on `edited X hr ago` in question. you would see old version.

Comment: Ok guys added my edited servlet codes back..so you can take a look. And of course followed what @ManojShukla said

Comment: Thanks for the update @LishaFathima but the servlet code is still missing :p see if you can add it again. ;)

Comment: @LishaFathima , in you jsp page, you are commenting out the declaration scriptlet unwittingly. `<%! int data=50; %> ` this is how it should be used, while you are commenting out its closing like this `<%! int data=50;  //some comment %>  `. Please either remove the comment or press enter after comments so that closing scriptlet would no get commented. `<%! int data=50;  %>  // comment here ` and this part goes to next line `%>`.

Answer (score 0):

You should parse your date instead of `System.out.println(myEvent.getStartDate());`

```
Date date = myEvent.getStartDate()
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");   
System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
```

Comment: But where do i put this? cuz i put it in my servlet and there's no difference. Same error

Comment: instead of line System.out.println(myEvent.getStartDate());

Comment: Thank you. I did that and it still shows the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your import type;

You imported `java.sql.Date` but you are willing to use `java.util.Date` features, this is very common mistakes we make when using IDE for suggestions and without looking for another imports available, we select the most upper one.. so don't get panic.

After modifying your import, it should work fine.

And to test that you can follow the solution given by @user7294900

> You should parse your date instead of `System.out.println(myEvent.getStartDate());`
>
> `Date date = myEvent.getStartDate();
>   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
>   System.out.println(sdf.format(date));`

If still not working, then at least the old error must have gone for now. And do post if any error persists, it will help us and others to learn more. :)

Comment: @LishaFathima did you just changed the import statement? If so, can you plz reflect it in your question code.. i have a doubt there.. so we'll try to figure out in deep.

Comment: Thanks @LishaFathima, meanwhile i was going through your servlet code, i found there too you are using `java.sql.Date` to set the values, please change it from there too.. and do let us know the result.

Comment: Yes it should, because of type mismatch. You must (should) use every where `java.util.Date`, only remaining thing what we can do is we need to have your servlet code, model code, and complete stack trace of the error.

Comment: It keep showing to rename in file..no idea why..if i do also the red lines are still there. It also says-The method valueOf(String) is undefined for the type Date

Answer (score 0):

I think you have problem with parsing the date . `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Date` are different. Database accepts only java.sql.Date.
For that, you need to convert java.util.Date into java.sql.Date.

```
Date startDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(request.getParameter("startDate"));

java.sql.Date sql_StartDate = new java.sql.Date(startDate.getTime() );
```

Convert it and set the value finally insert the value into the database.

Comment: This means I need to change my import also?

Comment: @LishaFathima yes .